# How to get all docs from users collection firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all docs from a collection in one shot without knowing the docs id's since they are random. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EOmg.png)I am creating an Admin panel so for that I want to show all sensor data without a specific UID how can I do this if I pass any user id and then show only this user info I want to get all user info in my admin panel.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:health_monitoring_app/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:health_monitoring_app/database/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:health_monitoring_app/model/sensor_data_model.dart';
import 'package:health_monitoring_app/provider/sensor_data_provider.dart';
import 'package:health_monitoring_app/view/user_data_list.dart';
import 'package:health_monitoring_app/view/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DoctorDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const DoctorDashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String routeNames = '/DoctorDashboard';

  @override
  State<DoctorDashboard> createState() => _DoctorDashboardState();
}

class _DoctorDashboardState extends State<DoctorDashboard> {
  final user = AuthService.currentUser;
  late SensorDataProvider _sensorDataProvider;

  List<Object> _dataList = [];

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _sensorDataProvider = Provider.of<SensorDataProvider>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    getUsersDataList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _dataList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return UserDataList(_dataList[index] as SensorDataModel);
        },
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                  // image: const DecorationImage(
                  //   image: AssetImage("assets/heart-beat.png"),
                  // )
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${user?.email}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )),
            ListTile(
              onTap: _doctorSignOut,
              leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              title: const Text('Sign Out'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _doctorSignOut() {
    AuthService.signOut().then((_) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, WelcomeScreen.routeNames);
    });
  }

  Future getUsersDataList() async {
    final uid = AuthService.currentUser?.uid;
    var data = await DatabaseHelper.db
        .collection('sensorData')
        .doc()
        .collection('userData')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .get();

    setState(() {
      _dataList =
          List.from(data.docs.map((doc) => SensorDataModel.fromSnapshot(doc)));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to get all documents from the `userData` collection of a specific `sensorData` document, or from all `sensorData` documents?

Comment: I want to get all userData collection from sensorData. sensorData->uid->userData->uid->documents

Comment: You can do this only with reading all `sensorData` documents, and set up a loop to get every `userData` collection for each `sensorData`. Depending on the number of documents this might result in a lot of reads, so proceed with caution.

Comment: As I see, you have a sub-collection called `userDat`a, that exists in each user document, right? So you need to get all documents that exist within all `userData` sub-collections?

Comment: yes I want to get all documents